# Replacing content of the fragment with navigation drawer item click

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

This is the test I am trying to do. I don't know if it can be done or not. 
What I am trying to do is, when the user clicks the Navigation Drawer item, I want to change the content of the fragment. I am not using different fragments, actually I am using only one fragment.

What I want to achieve is, when the user click the drawer menu item, the fragment should display the data as per the click, for simplicity just the name of the menu item in the fragment.

With use of the single fragment, I want to have different content with the different menu item click.

The Menu items in the Navigation Drawer are dynamically created as that is intended to be shown from the db, and the number of menu items can be variable.

EDIT:
NavigationDrawerActivity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Fragment testFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        menu.add(0,i,0,"Set "+ i);
    }

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    testFragment = new TestFragment();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            // Handle the camera action
        if (id == i){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("SET_ID", "this is test"+i);
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            testFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, testFragment).commit();

        }

    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

TestFragment

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

TextView textView;

public TestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    String idValue = getArguments().getString("SET_ID");
    Log.d("TEST_VALUE***", idValue);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.just_Text);
    textView.setText("Set id is: "+idValue);


    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: what did you try? paste the code you tried...

Comment: @AmitJangid , I have update the question with the code.
What I am trying to achieve is change the content of the single fragment with dynamically created menu items. Actually I want to show the different recyclerview with each menu items clicked. Just for the test, I am using the id of the menu item to be displayed when the user clicks the menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the below line inside `onNavigationItemSelected` for lopp

```
testFragment = new TestFragment(); // this line
```

Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();


for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        // Handle the camera action
    if (id == i){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("SET_ID", "this is test"+i);
        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        testFragment = new TestFragment(); // add this line in your code.
        testFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, testFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Check this it might work...